# iTunes development in C#

Tags: c#, itunes

I am a c# web developer but I am doing a side project that involves iTunes. I am looking at a few projects from codeplex and some of them contain Interop.iTunesLib.dll. This old article also contains the same file http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=12369.

Does anyone know where this file came from?

Thank you.

Comment: The [Contributor](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=580163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aforementioned iTunes COM object is installed along with the app.  Here is an example of [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RemovingDeadTracksDuplicatesThatDontExistFromITunesUsingC.aspx) using the COM object to delete duplicate tracks.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I found out the Interop.iTunesLib.dll came from the installation of iTunes and I can add it by adding a COM reference (it shows up after the installation of iTunes).

Answer (score 0):

When you install iTunes, the `iTunes.exe` application gets registered as COM server (likely with `regsvr32.exe`).  It will have a small key group in the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registry section with the GUID of: `9E93C96F-CF0D-43F6-8BA8-B807A3370712`

To reference this COM server, in your C# program, you would add the following COMReference property to your csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="iTunesLib">
    <Guid>{9E93C96F-CF0D-43F6-8BA8-B807A3370712}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>13</VersionMinor>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This tells the build system to use the `tlbimp` program to create a managed type library for the COM server that your managed module can reference.  The `tlbimp` program will create a module called `Interop.iTunesLib.dll` and the build system will place a copy of this in both your `bin` and `obj` directories.

If you don't have iTunes installed, then there will be no COM server registered and your build will fail.

However, if you managed (no pun intended) to save a copy of `Interop.iTunesLib.dll`, then without having iTunes installed, you can reference it like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMFileReference Include="Interop.iTunesLib.dll">
        <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMFileReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

In the `include attribute`, you can / may need to add a path component, as well.  There are probably a few versions of `Interop.iTunesLib.dll` floating around the internet likely from different versions of `iTunes.exe`.  Best to get this file from a trusted source.

While using the `COMFileReference` property will allow the project to build properly, attempting to execute the iTunes related functionality will crash the program, because that functionality is located in `iTunes.exe`, which in this situation, is not present.

In my project, I get around this by first checking to see `iTunes.exe` exists (`\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe`), before attempting to execute any of the iTunes functionality.